# Jar files for PDF generation through Java

Tags: file, jar, pdf-generation

Where can i get the following jar files from-:
adobe-livecycle-client.jar
adobe-usermanager-client.jar
adobe-utilities.jar?
How do i download these jar files?

Answer (score 1):

You buy them. And from the looks of things, [they're not going to be cheap](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/).

If you are looking for a free, open-source solution for generating PDFs, the most widely-used solution is iText, available [here](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/).

Answer (score 0):

well for java based PDF solutions...we dont have a clean way i guess-still.. all solutions are primitive and kind of workarounds... No easy solution for 
1. Designing a template of a PDF 
2. Then at runtime using java, populate data into this template...either using xml or other datasources...

such a simple requirement and NONE has a good "open-source and free" solution yet !

Eclipse BIRT comes close.. but does not handle Barcode elements ..OOB.